# Loop Through 1 SQL Query, Instead Of Using 2 Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below I have a variable with two basic SELECT statements. If the user can only use one variable, @StartDate, to enter a date parameter, how can a query be looped through to only use one SELECT statement instead of two like you see below. So, imagine you don't have both queries, but one query and it can only be ran once but satisfy the 2 conditions in the WHERE clauses below, which are "FullDate = @StartDate" and "Fulldate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0) AND @StartDate". SO, essentially I am trying to squeeze two SELECT statements into one and provide the relevant data from both queries. UNION ALL cannot be used here.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20170610'

SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM(MoneySpent) AS 'Spent'  
FROM
    TableOne  
WHERE
    FullDate = @StartDate;  
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName

SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM(MoneySpent) AS 'Spent'    
FROM
    TableOne    
WHERE
    Fulldate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0) AND @StartDate;  
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Comment: Are you sure Fulldate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0) AND @StartDate  is correct?

Comment: `Fulldate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0) AND @StartDate` doesn't make sense. Do you mean between those two? (e.g. between the start of the month of @StartDate and @StartDate?)

Comment: Something you need to know about BETWEEN is that it includes the endpoints, there for anything in the first select will be in your second select as is anyways, so just remove the first select and your fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two dates @Date1 and @Date2, then you can use this:

```
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FullDate = @Date1 THEN MoneySpent ELSE 0 END) AS 'SpentDate1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN FullDate = @Date2 THEN MoneySpent ELSE 0 END) AS 'SpentDate2'  
FROM
    TableOne  
WHERE
    FullDate = @Date1 OR FullDate = @Date2
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

BTW, UNION ALL can be used as well, you just need wrap it as subquery and use additional GROUP BY

Comment: What if you're only allowed one date parameter and not allowed to use UNION ALL?

Comment: use above query - it is without union all, and date1 and date2 are just placeholders, replace it with your own condition

Answer (score 0):

Something you need to know about BETWEEN is that it includes the endpoints, so you only need the second query to obtain what you are looking for.

```
SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SUM(MoneySpent) AS 'Spent'    
FROM
    TableOne    
WHERE
    Fulldate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0) AND @StartDate;  
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first query is already covered by the second query.

```
            SELECT  FirstName ,
                    LastName ,
                    SUM(MoneySpent) AS 'Spent'
            FROM    TableOne
            WHERE   Fulldate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0)
                             AND     @StartDate 
            GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

But for the sake of argument, one of many options is that you can put the relevant data of each query into a temporary table.

E.g.

```
        DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2017.06.10';


        IF ( OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTbl') IS NOT NULL )
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #tempTbl
            END

        CREATE TABLE #tempTbl
            (
              ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
                     PRIMARY KEY ,
              FirstName VARCHAR(100) ,
              LastName VARCHAR(100) ,
              Spent MONEY
            )

        INSERT  INTO #tempTbl
                ( FirstName ,
                  LastName ,
                  Spent
                )
                SELECT  FirstName ,
                        LastName ,
                        SUM(MoneySpent) AS 'Spent'
                FROM    TableOne
                WHERE   FullDate = @StartDate

        INSERT  INTO #tempTbl
                ( FirstName ,
                  LastName ,
                  Spent
                )
                SELECT  FirstName ,
                        LastName ,
                        SUM(MoneySpent) AS 'Spent'
                FROM    TableOne
                WHERE   Fulldate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0)
                                 AND     @StartDate 

        SELECT  FirstName,LastName,Spent
        FROM    #tempTbl
        GROUP BY FirstName, LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,Here you nitice that One Resultset is subset of another resultset.
In other word,Range Between condition satify equal condition.So result is not repeated.

Example `using AdventureWorks2012`

```
    DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20020224'
    DECLARE @StartDate1 DATE = '20020303'

select a.BusinessEntityID
,a.RateChangeDate,sum(a.rate)  Rate
from HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory a
where a.RateChangeDate
 BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0) AND @StartDate
 or a.RateChangeDate=@StartDate1
 GROUP by a.BusinessEntityID,a.RateChangeDate
```

here Result of both date is visisble (**`6 rows`**)

if we make it this

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '20020224'
DECLARE @StartDate1 DATE = StartDate
```

here since `between condtion` satify `RateChangeDate=@StartDate1`
so output is only **`5 rows`**

so what you are thinking is cannot be achieve.

If I had same problem then I will use only  `select ... FullDate between`

And in front end I will `pull data for fulldate=@StartDate`

If you really use 2 Select like now you doing then do this,

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT 
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Fulldate,
    SUM(MoneySpent) AS 'Spent'    
FROM
    TableOne    
WHERE
    Fulldate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @StartDate), 0) AND @StartDate;  
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName,Fulldate
)
select *,0 flg from cte
union ALL
select * ,1 flg from cte 
where Fulldate=@StartDate
```